# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode when writing to file

Tags: python, encoding

I can't figure out why my code raises:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0161' in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Everything is probably in unicode and `string.decode or encode utf-8` doesn't work too.

```
def create_active_orders_xlsx():
    orders = drevo_models.Order.objects.filter(confirmed=True,done=False)
    f = open('example2.csv','w')
    for order in orders:
        f.write(order.get_csv_line()) #.encode('utf-8') tried but the same error
    f.close()

class Order(models.Model):
    ....
    ....
    def get_csv_line(self):
        return u'"'+u'";"'.join([u'{}'.format(x) for x in [self.id,self.first_name,self.last_name,self.psc,
                                             self.city,self.street,self.number,
                                             self.wet_wood,self.dry_wood,self.stelinka,self.briquette,
                                             self.price]]) + u'"'
```

Do you know where the problem is?

Comment: Are you sure you get the same error with `order.get_csv_line().encode('utf8'))`? Or did you add the `.encode()` call to the `f.write()` return value?

Comment: Also, without a *full traceback* you are leaving us guessing as to where that exception is being thrown, in what context.

Comment: Last but not least: don't try to re-invent the CSV wheel. Use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) (but do use the `UnicodeWriter` class from the examples section).

Comment: It would also be nice if you mention which Python version you're using, since Unicode handling in Python 2 is quite different to Python 3. I guess from the `u'...'` stuff that you're using Py 2, but that syntax is also valid in Py 3.